# Alternative program foe vSphere with VMWare ESXi

Tags: vmware-esxi, vmware-vsphere

I've bought my dedicated server and chose VMWare ESXi and manage everything using the vSphere 5 client. It says "60-day evaluation" on the client. Does this mean I only have 60 days to trial vSphere client before I have to purchase their expensive license or what? I'm a bit confused.

If that's what that means, what's a free alternative of vSphere 5?

Comment: [**Try just a little harder...**](http://www.vmware.com/products/vsphere-hypervisor/overview.html)

Comment: I can use that instead of the vSphere client?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The vSphere client doesn't require a license. The warning is related to your vSphere host. It means that it's running in 60 day trial mode where you can use features such as HA, DRS, FT, etc. After 60 days you'll only be able to use the features of the free edition of vSphere.

Comment: Does this include managing my dedicated server? I use pretty much the "Add new VM," datastore feature, edit VM settings, etc.

Comment: You can manage your host with the vSphere client regardless of what edition/kit/license (or lack of) you have. The warning is in regards to your host, not your client. You really ought to look at the edition and kit comparisons to see what features are available with each edition and kit. - http://www.vmware.com/products/datacenter-virtualization/vsphere/compare-editions.html - http://www.vmware.com/products/datacenter-virtualization/vsphere/compare-kits.html

Comment: Thanks for a great answer and doing so respectfully. It's sad I can't come here without getting down-voted 5 times.

Comment: Glad to help. Don't let the down votes discourage you. It happens to all of us (mostly).